# jenkins and install4j integration

Tags: java, jenkins, install4j

I tried to integrate the jenkins and install4j to create the executable file but getting an error once execute the build on jenkins

> build_dist.xml:6: taskdef class com.install4j.Install4JTask cannot be
>   found

Can some one please help to configure the install4j in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

The ant task is described here:

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/cli/ant.html

The taskdef has the form

```
  <taskdef name="install4j"
           classname="com.install4j.Install4JTask"
           classpath="C:\Program Files\install4j\bin\ant.jar"/>
```

The error message that you get suggests that the class path is not correct.